# Accessing Parent Model from child element of ManyToManyField (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having a models.py as follows

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    auther_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    comment_body = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)

class Post(models.Model):
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment)
```

So let's say i have a comment Object Instance which's id is 2 and raw content

How to get parent post_id which contains this comment??

Comment: You use a `ManyToManyField`, hence there can be zero, one, or more related `Post`s. It does not seem to make much sense to model this with an m2m field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `related_name`. Small change adding: `related_name='posts'`: think of it like "if we start from the opposite side, what would be the name to use" (it's always plural).

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    comment_body = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)

class Post(models.Model):
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment, related_name='posts')
```

Now you can do:

```
for post in Comment.objects.get(pk=12).posts.all():
    print(post.xxx)
```